# Connect WIX to subfolder of domain

Tags: web, dns, subdomain, web-hosting, velo

I have a website example.com that is hosted on AWS. The main site is being produced by a development team. I have a landing page created through WIX.com. I would like to point the landing page to something like "example.com/promo" without interfering with the rest of example.com. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you just need to use URL Rewrite on your code, so when people browse to example.com, it will automatically redirect to example.com/promo.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I do not think this solves my problem because I still want example.com itself to be accessible... example.com will have the main site that's hosted on AWS.. and then example.com/promo should just be this WIX landing page

Comment: No... No... You can't do that. You better create promo as subdomain. So, people will access using promo.yourdomain.com. You can point your A record to WIX IP address.